# COM objects (PC*MILER 29) - map not working

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, com

We have gotten most of a new installation of PC*MILER 29 (a transportation stop, route, and mapping app) to work. However, the mapping function fails when creating a map.

The code is:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = "VBSCRIPT" %>
<% Option Explicit %>

<% 
' *******************
'   VB Init
' *******************

    ' VARIABLES:
    Dim errorstring     ' catch errors to display
    Dim command         ' which button was pressed
    Dim i               ' counter
    'Dim mapObj             ' the map object
    'Dim validmap       ' map in a valid state?
    Dim stops
    Dim x_coord, y_coord ' coordinates of map view
    Dim x_zoomLevel 
    Dim y_zoomLevel 
    Dim detailLevel      ' detail level
    Dim currentStop
    Dim tripID
    Dim map
    Dim mapSettings
    Dim reportOptions
    Dim routeType

    ' no errors to start
    errorstring = ""

    ' which button was pressed???

    Err.Clear
    'On Error Resume Next

set map = Session("map")
tripID = Session("currentTrip").ID
map.frameRoute tripID
stops = ""
For i = 0 To Session("currentTrip").numStops() - 1
    currentStop = Session("currentTrip").getStop2(i)
    stops = stops & currentStop & "|"
    map.plotPin "MyLayer", "pin" & (i-1), "1..6", "Red Truck", currentStop, ""
    'map.plotLabel "MyLayer", i, "1..6", "Red|30", currentStop, currentStop
Next

Session("currentTrip").TravelDistance()
set reportOptions = Session("currentTrip").GetOptions()

If Err = 0 Then
    If reportOptions.RouteType = 0 Then
        routeType = "practical"
    Else
        routeType = "shortest"
    End If

    map.PlotTrip "MyLayer", tripID, "1..6", "Green|5", stops, routeType

    Set mapSettings = map.MapSettings

    command = Request("action")

    select case command
    case "Zoom In"
        map.ZoomIn
    case "Zoom Out"
        map.ZoomOut
    case "More Detail"
        map.MoreDetail
    case "Less Detail"
        map.LessDetail
    case "PanE"
        map.Pan 2, 0.4
    case "PanW"
        map.Pan 6, 0.4
    case "PanN"
        map.Pan 0, 0.4
    case "PanS"
        map.Pan 4, 0.4
    case "panNE"
        map.pan 1, 0.4
    case "panSE"
        map.pan 3, 0.4
    case "panSW"
        map.pan 5, 0.4
    case "panNW"
        map.pan 7, 0.4
    case else
        map.FramePinMap("MyLayer")
        map.LessDetail()
    End Select

    Dim gifId
    gifId =  CStr(map.mapid) 

    Dim GIF_HEIGHT, GIF_WIDTH 
    GIF_HEIGHT = 500
    GIF_WIDTH = 750

    map.SetGifDirectory request.servervariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") + "maps\"

    Dim str, gifstring
    str = FormatDateTime(Now)
    str = Replace(str,"/","_")
    str = Replace(str,":","_")
    str = Replace(str," ","_")
    gifstring = gifId +"_" + str
    gifId =  gifId + "_" + str + ".gif"

    map.CreateGifFile GIF_WIDTH, GIF_HEIGHT, gifId, 4

    ' check that the mapping object exists
    ' it is created in the global.asa on application start
    If (application("g_pcmmapmgr").IsOK <= 0) Then
        errorstring = "Error: PC*MILER mapping object not found.<br><br>"
    End If
Else
    errorString = "Map Not Available"
    Err.Clear
End If          
%>
```

The tracing errors at line 109 above:

```
map.CreateGifFile GIF_WIDTH, GIF_HEIGHT, gifId, 4
```

I'm at a loss as to what might be going on.

All DLLs that I know of are registered and correct in the registry. That took a reinstall of the app.

ERROR LOG:

```
132.  -ASP_SCRIPT_TRACE_COM_CALL_END 


FilePath
C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\MILER\MAP.ASP 

LineNumber
99 

CurrentStatement
map.SetGifDirectory request.servervariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH") + "maps\" 

SizeOfStatement
75 



0 ms

Verbose
133.  -ASP_SCRIPT_TRACE_COM_CALL_START 


FilePath
C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\MILER\MAP.ASP 

LineNumber
109 

CurrentStatement
map.CreateGifFile GIF_WIDTH, GIF_HEIGHT, gifId, 4 

SizeOfStatement
49 


329 ms

Verbose
134.  -ASP_SCRIPT_TRACE_COM_CALL_END 


FilePath
C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\MILER\MAP.ASP 

LineNumber
109 

CurrentStatement
map.CreateGifFile GIF_WIDTH, GIF_HEIGHT, gifId, 4 

SizeOfStatement
49 


0 ms

Error
135.  -ASP_LOG_ERROR 


LineNumber
109 

ErrorCode
80004005 

Description
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say? What does the server log say? Are the values passed to the method what they're supposed to be?

Comment: The tracing is:
_133.  -ASP_SCRIPT_TRACE_COM_CALL_START 


FilePath
C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\MILER\MAP.ASP 

LineNumber
109 

CurrentStatement
map.CreateGifFile GIF_WIDTH, GIF_HEIGHT, gifId, 4 

SizeOfStatement
49 


329 ms

Verbose
134.  -ASP_SCRIPT_TRACE_COM_CALL_END 


FilePath
C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\MILER\MAP.ASP 

LineNumber
109 

CurrentStatement
map.CreateGifFile GIF_WIDTH, GIF_HEIGHT, gifId, 4 

SizeOfStatement
49 


0 ms

Error
135.  -ASP_LOG_ERROR 


LineNumber
109 

ErrorCode
80004005 

Description_

Comment: Please edit your question. The information is  unreadable in a comment.

Comment: BTW, the exact same code from PC*MILER 22 on another server works just fine.

Comment: @KarenRaymond-Hart Then it probably is not an issue with the code, but an issue of either the server configuration or difference in a dependency.  The error code 80004005 would seem to indicate the latter as that code means "Server failed to load application"